# Error with summing columns in R (invalid 'type' (character) of argument)?

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
structure(list(Patient_ID = c("1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", 
"1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", "1234"), Unit_Type = c("ABC", 
"ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "DEF", "DEF", "DEF", "GHI"), Status = c("Returned", 
"R", "R", "R", "T", "T", 
"T", "T", "T")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

and have used the following calculation on it:

```
df <- df %>%
  count(ID, Unit_Type, Status) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(Unit, Status), values_from = n)
```

I want to sum `'ABC_R'` and `'ABC_T'` by `ID` (I know the example dataset only has one unique patient ID, but my real dataset has many more), but I keep getting the following error message:

```
> aggregate(df, by=list(df$ABC_T, df$ABC_R), FUN=sum, na.rm = TRUE)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

Comment: Sure, its structure(list(Patient_ID = "1234", ABC_Returned = 4L, ABC_Transfused = 1L, 
    DEF_Transfused = 3L, GHI_Transfused = 1L, ABC_Ordered = 5), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you look for this:

The reason why you get the error is that with your code you try to sum also the first column which is a character column, subsetting by df[,-1] should work:

```
aggregate(df[,-1], by=list(df$ABC_Transfused, df$ABC_Returned), FUN=sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

```
  Group.1 Group.2 ABC_Returned ABC_Transfused DEF_Transfused GHI_Transfused
1       1       4            4              1              3              1
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(ABC_ordered = ABC_Returned + ABC_Transfused)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 × 6
  Patient_ID ABC_Returned ABC_Transfused DEF_Transfused GHI_Transfused ABC_ordered
  <chr>             <int>          <int>          <int>          <int>       <int>
1 1234                  4              1              3              1           5
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what youre looking for?

I added another dataframe with another ID, hopefully to clarify, but I think you want a rowwise operation.

Since the data is already aggregated in the count step I dont think you need to do any additional grouping since one observation is one patient

```
data <- structure(list(Patient_ID = c("1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", 
"1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", "1234"), Unit_Type = c("ABC", 
"ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "DEF", "DEF", "DEF", "GHI"), Status = c("Returned", 
"Returned", "Returned", "Returned", "Transfused", "Transfused", 
"Transfused", "Transfused", "Transfused")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))

data2 <- structure(list(Patient_ID = c("1235", "1235", "1235", "1235", 
"1235", "1235", "1235", "1235", "1235"), Unit_Type = c("ABC", 
"ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "DEF", "DEF", "DEF", "GHI"), Status = c("Returned", 
"Returned", "Returned", "Returned", "Transfused", "Transfused", 
"Transfused", "Transfused", "Transfused")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))

data%>%
  rbind(data2) -> data_full


data_full2 <- data_full %>%
  count(Patient_ID, Unit_Type, Status) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(Unit_Type, Status), values_from = n)


data_full2%>%
  rowwise()%>%
  mutate(ABC_Ordered = sum(c(ABC_Returned,
                             ABC_Transfused),
                           na.rm = TRUE))%>%
  ungroup() -> data_full3
```